# Can I use a Google map in my PhD thesis?

Tags: thesis, copyright

I want to use a map downloaded from Google maps in my PhD thesis. Does Google allow me to do this? Do I need permission from Google?

Comment: Same here, have you found an easy way to do that?

Comment: Related: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/77933/permission-to-include-a-segment-from-google-maps-as-a-figure-in-a-publication

Answer (score 16):

Google provides you the right to employ a Google Maps map on your thesis. See [Permission Guidelines for Google Maps and Google Earth](http://www.google.com/permissions/geoguidelines.html) (first two points of *The basics* and *Using maps in print*).

However, they ask you to provide correct [attribution](http://www.google.com/permissions/geoguidelines/attr-guide.html) for those pictures. It will be something like “*Map data ©20xx Google, Sanborn*”. As they write, you have to find the correct copyright statement on the map you would like to reproduce in your thesis.

Alternatively, it may be possible for you to use  [OpenStreetMap](http://openstreetmap.org) which is [Open Data material](http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright) and has more permissive licensing.

Comment: There isn't a more straight-forward way? Like, add this line as a reference "Google bla bla bla..".

Comment: @Pedro77, the attribution sentence "Map data ©20xx Google, Sanborn" is quite straightforward. You just need to find the correct string, which is displayed on the map you want to insert. For example, [the map of my university](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Free+University+of+Bozen-Bolzano/@46.4980788,11.3503271,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x47829e795d3a902d:0xdc939b140fa714ad) currently says "Map data © 2015 Google" (bottom right)

Comment: Ok nice, thanks. What about Street view or Sea View? There is only month and year.

Comment: @Pedro77 make sure you read the guidelines, as [they mention the case of Street View](http://www.google.com/permissions/geoguidelines.html#streetview). It seems that you cannot use a screenshot of Street View for a project unless the picture comes from Google API, or you embed it in a website. You need to contact them for different purposes: streetview-academic@google.com